# Learn about vs. know about

Tags: word-choice

> I want to **learn** about different cultures.
>
> I want to **know** about different cultures.

Do these two sentences mean the same?

Answer (score 1):

They both are grammatical, but they mean two different things:

- **I want to *learn* about different cultures**. This means I want to **gain** **knowledge** by *studying*, *practicing*, *being taught*, or *experiencing* different cultures.
- **I want to *know* about different cultures**. This means I want to **have the information** about different cultures in my mind. There's nothing about gaining knowledge, but just having it.